# Why is my object culled when I have backface culling turned off?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, visibility

[image]
As you can see in the first image, The object is selected so it has a selected box around it but you can clearly see through it. In the second image, you can see it from the top side. How can I get it so that I can see both sides?

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the images I posted?

Comment: oops sorry  ;)  I didn't enlarge them

Comment: could you please share your file? at least the object?

Comment: Well, it just fixed itself somehow. I booted it back up and it's working fine. I don't believe I did anything

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wasn't displayed correctly as your Backface Culling option was off but I may miss something, or it might be a bug...